# Convert string into mathematical expression

Tags: c#, variables

I'm trying to convert a text from textbox in a WinForms. I have an application which is drawing charts from linear equation (fe x^2+2x+3) and I need to have output in mathematical expression to make it work.

Main problem I'm facing is I can't find way to convert string "Math.pow(x,2)" to (I don't know if I'm doing this correct) dynamic answer = Math.pow(x,2);

Can you please help me?

Comment: You probably want to look into existing libraries for handling this kind of task, you'll likely get a more robust and wider reaching implementation

Comment: you can build symbol library based on the standard notation , review: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/math-equation-editor-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: You can implement your own calculator with a finite set of functions. It's not too hard. Also you can find the algorithms to do so in almost every book about programming for beginners.